# Densities in Number Fields

Tags: number-theory

The  natural density for a subset of the set of natural numbers is well known, see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

There is some generalization of the natural density to the Gaussiam integers or (more generally) to the integers in a number field?

I found some papers that generalize the Schnirelmann density (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnirelmann_density) to higer dimensions. What about the natural density?

Comment: http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/chebotarev.pdf

Comment: Yes such things are done. Typically one will consider the count of the elements with (absolute) norm below some value for this, and see how it behaves. Note that this is often better done for (pricipal) ideals, or up to associates, since in a case were one has infinitely many units one has issues otherwise, as the number of actual *elements* with norm $1$ could be already countable.